# How to delay my printing function so I can see when each object is printed

Tags: c#, wpf

In my program I have an array of objects, and I want to print each object one at a time with a delay.

Right now this is my Draw() function:

```
    public void Draw()
    {
        myCanvas.Children.Clear();
        foreach (Square Sq in MyDrawings)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                sq.Draw();
            }));
        }
    }
```

My sq.draw() function, currently draws a rectangle, and adds it to the canvas:

```
             rect = new Rectangle
             {
                 Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                 StrokeThickness = 0.5,
                 Fill = Brushes.Black,
                 Height = Width,
                 Width = Width
             };
             Canvas.SetTop(rect, x * Width);
             Canvas.SetLeft(rect, y * Width);
             Form.myCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
```

I've tried adding a Thread.Sleep(); in the main Draw() function, but it seems to block the UI thread, and when it unblocks, the whole Array has been drawn.

I've also tried to use a DispatcherTimer, but I don't know what delay to add as I want to print each object, not based on time.

Fixed Code:

```
    public void Draw()
    {
        myCanvas.Children.Clear();
        foreach (Square Sq in MyDrawings)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    sq.Draw();
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just  want iterate over collection and launch async/parallel execution of print jobs one-after-another, you may do something like

```
    foreach (Square Sq in MyDrawings)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            sq.Draw();
            Thread.Sleep(SOME_MILLISECONDS_TO_WAIT);
        }));
    }
```

This will suspend iteration on amount of `SOME_MILLISECONDS_TO_WAIT` ms specified, and iterate over another element in collection. 
Naturally if you concerned about feedback from `Task`, or want to be in control of Task's run, as much as it possible, you will need to add more to this code.

Comment: I've edited my main post with the code you suggested, I had to include the dispatcher, otherwise the UI thread would block. After using your suggestion my program still doesn't print the code correctly, I even used a stopwatch to measure the time it takes the method's execution time, and it's 83ms, eventhough I added 100ms wait time, between each loop

Comment: @BaronSensei: what does it mean "correctly"? Don't you want program send a print job to printer, wait a little bit and sends another one, even though previous is not yet finished ?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't more clear, I intend my program to: print object ->wait ~50-100ms->print object->...  but with my previous implementation and yours, it waits <1s and prints all the objects at once, eventhough there's a 100ms wait in between each loop.

Comment: That works perfectly, Thanks! It seems that my previous implementation using Thread.Sleep() was wrong as I had it inside the dispatcher invoke and it froze the whole UI until finished, when I place it outside of the Invoke it works perfectly.

Comment: @BaronSensei: most likely you where putting `Sleep` outside of secondary thread, so it was blocking main one.